# Is Visio capable of linking to information?

Tags: software-rec, microsoft-visio

I need to create a document that will link or balloon details on certain objects.  I'm trying to use visio for this, but I'm not sure if it is the best tool.

My first document is a map of my office that I use for auditing, I would like to have like a dot or name that when clicked will take me to a list of information on that desk.  Such as Computer name, computer model, phone number.  Then I have a server topology view that I would like to be able to click on the servers and view hardware information and roles information.

Is visio capable of doing this? If so, what is the technical term for what I'm trying to do so I can better find tutorials?  Or what other software would be nicer to use?

Comment: What version of visio?

Comment: I have Visio 2010

Answer (score 1):

One option for you is to use **Shape Data**

First, enable the **Shape Data Window** on the **Data** tab

[image]

Then when you select a shape, any associated data will be shown. Below is a simple rectangle with no data.

[image]

To add data, just right click ...

[image]

Many Visio shapes already have shape data properties defined for them. For example the Server shape below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For MS Visio 2007 you can `insert - comment` and this will create a comment you can type into and click to expand. You can also `insert - shape screentip` which will display information when you hover over your item.